# Alias for a mysql case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to set an alias for the case statement in the following query. The query works fine but the last column header shows as the case statement in full. You can have a look at what I mean at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e9f028cf740e737e7f648020efcaa69). I am trying to get the difference between the current salary at a row and the next salary found for that employee in a list of employees.

```
select r.totalSalary, r.nextTotalSalary , 
 (case when isnull(r.nextTotalSalary)= 1 then r.totalSalary
    else nextTotalSalary
    end ) - r.totalSalary 
 from (
    SELECT 
        pi.empid,
        pi.totalSalary,
        LEAD(pi.totalSalary,1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY pi.empid
            ORDER BY pi.effectivefrom ) nextTotalSalary
    FROM 
     Report pi where pi.empid = 200 ) r ;
```

When i try to place an alias as `end as nextTotalSalary` the query won't execute. Error is *"Select is not valid at this position for this server version .."*

How can i set an alias for the third column?

Comment: Are you putting the `as nextTotalSalary` inside or outside of the parenthesis?  If you are doing `(...) - r.totalSalary` then you need the `as nextTotalSalary` after the whole expression (which includes the subtraction).

Comment: @RocketHazmat it was inside the bracket, just after the end

Comment: AS does not work with arbitrary expressions, it needs to be after the entire expression for one of the columns (so outside the bracket and after the ` - r.totalSalary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AS`. For example:

```
select r.totalSalary,  r.nextTotalSalary ,  ( case  when isnull(r.nextTotalSalary)= 1 then r.totalSalary
else nextTotalSalary
end  ) - r.totalSalary as nextTotalSalary
from (
SELECT 
    pi.empid,
    pi.totalSalary,
    LEAD(pi.totalSalary,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY pi.empid
        ORDER BY pi.effectivefrom ) nextTotalSalary
FROM 
 Report pi where pi.empid = 200 ) r ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below query:

```
select r.totalSalary,  r.nextTotalSalary ,  ( case  when isnull(r.nextTotalSalary)= 1 then r.totalSalary
else nextTotalSalary
end  ) - r.totalSalary  AS TOTAL_SALARY
from (
SELECT 
    pi.empid,
    pi.totalSalary,
    LEAD(pi.totalSalary,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY pi.empid
        ORDER BY pi.effectivefrom ) nextTotalSalary
FROM 
 Report pi where pi.empid = 200 ) r ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is more complicated than it needs to be:

```
SELECT pi.empid, pi.totalSalary,
       LEAD(pi.totalSalary) OVER (PARTITION BY pi.empid ORDER BY pi.effectivefrom) as next_totalSalary,
       (LEAD(pi.totalSalary, 1, pi.TotalSalary) OVER (PARTITION BY pi.empid ORDER BY pi.effectivefrom) -
        TotalSalary
       ) as diff
FROM Report pi 
WHERE pi.empid = 200;
```

This uses the three-argument form of `LEAD()` so no `NULL` comparison is needed at all.

Comment: I just tested the above on the data on dbfiddle link i provided. Null is coming on the last column. If that is the expected result from the query I understand. However I do not want to show null. I want the last total salary to show if there is no next total salary. That was why i using the case statement in my query

Comment: @Bisoux . . . The only way the last column could be `NULL` is if `pi.TotalSalary` is every `NULL`.  The `LEAD()` is not going to generate a `NULL` value in any other situation.

Comment: is every NULL ?  Not sure I follow. Did you try your script on the dbfiddle link I provided?

Comment: @Bisoux . . . That should be "is ever `NULL`", but I cannot change it now.

Comment: Hmmm, still not clear for me. As you can see my sample data does not have null in any field for all rows. The query you gave returns a null for the last nextTotalsalary field.

Comment: @Bisoux . . . When I run this on your data, the last column is never `NULL`:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=611b7f1ecd252fb05bc1200533ed390f.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220663/discussion-between-bisoux-and-gordon-linoff).